# Apply filter on Page objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm building an API that accepts for my "/search" request multiple parameters so that I can filter results with `findAll(Example<T> example)`. In the second stage I filter non trivial types (`Date`) to narrow down my results, which works fine.

The problem now arises where I want to implement pagination. Spring data offers the `findAll(Example<T> example, Pageable page)` method, which creates a `Page<T>` element for me, which is no more applicable to my filtering mechanisms.
Though `Page<T>` offers a `.filter(Predicate p)` function, this converts my Page to a Streamable, which is not what I need for pagination.

How can I further filter a `Page<T>` object without ending up with a unintended data format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by first filtering my result set without the pagination information, and later applying the submitted pagination parameters.

```
int startIndex = page * size;
int endIndex = (startIndex + size) > myList.size() ? myList.size() : (startIndex + size);
JsonPage<>(myList.subList(startIndex, endIndex), PageRequest.of(page, size), myList.size());
```

That is way more intuitive than creating the page object and unpack it to get the filterable objects.